# MS SQL SELECT Query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables PHONE and RULES.

I store a list of phones('s information) in the Phone table and On the UI (UserInterface)
I have a screen where user can create Rules using a bunch of drop down filters.The Filters on the UI are on  Phone Name, Color, Model,and  ScreenWidth.

User can create rules by selecting these filters and the values they select from dropdown goes to the Rules table.
Two such rules are in the below table;the first one is to get all iphone 4S phones and the second one is to get all phones which are white in color.

I need a MS SQL SELECT statement that I can use to get all records on the phone table which match Rule1 or Rule2 in the Rules table.

### PHONE

```
**Name  Color   Model   ScreenWidth**       
iPhone  White   4S         4        
iPhone  Black   4S         4        
iPhone  Gold    5S         4        
iPhone  Silver  5S         4        
Samsung White   S5         5        
Samsung Black   S5         5        
HTC     White   One        4
```

### RULES

```
**RuleName  ManufactureerFilter ColorFilter ModelFilter**   ScreenWidthFilter   
Rule1              iPhone          NULL         4S             NULL 
Rule2               NULL           White        NULL           NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

This request should work:

```
 SELECT * FROM Phone p INNER JOIN Rules r ON  
(r.ManufactureerFilter IS NULL OR p.Name = r.ManufactureerFilter) AND
(r.ColorFilter IS NULL OR p.Color = r.ColorFilter) AND
(r.ScreenWidthFilter IS NULL OR p.ScreenWidth = r.ScreenWidthFilter) AND
(r.ModelFilter IS NULL OR p.Model  = r.ModelFilter)
WHERE r.RuleName IN ('Rule1', 'Rule1' ...)
```

- See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c1f89/1).

Comment: You should replace `||` with `OR`.

Comment: This Query works but I was looking for a more optimized query.Because both of my tables have several thousands of records and I can ask for a combination of rules in hundreds.